# No block given(yield) rails error on conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a nested form called Transaction that includes a child object called Banking Information Form. The banking information validations should not be triggered when the parent's (transaction) transaction_mechanism field is set to "cheque". For some reason when I set the transaction_mechanism to "cheque" in the form, it's still calling the banking information form validations. In the bank_information_form model I have a method called cheque_transaction? that should prevent the validations from triggering if the transaction_mechanism is "cheque", but I'm receiving an error.

**The error**

```
no block given (yield)
```

**transaction.rb**

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Require packages
  require 'time'

  # Associations
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :banking_information_form

  # Nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :banking_information_form

  # Validations
  validates_associated :banking_information_form
  validate  :check_debit_or_credit
  validates :transaction_mechanism, :transaction_kind, :debit, :salesforce_id, presence: true
  validate  :debit, :credit,numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

**banking_information_form.rb**

```
class BankingInformationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  # Belongs to :transaction
  belongs_to :owner, foreign_key: "transaction_id", class_name: "Transaction"

  # Validations
  validates :financial_institution, :transit_number, :bank_account_number, presence: true, :unless =>    :cheque_transaction?
  validates :transit_number, length: {is: 5,
                                  too_short: "Your transit number is 5 digits long.",
                                  too_long: "Your transit number is 5 digits long."}
  validates :bank_account_number, length: {minimum: 4, maximum: 12,
                                  too_short: "Your bank account number will be between 4 and 12 digits long.",
                                  too_long: "Your bank account number will be between 4 and 12 digits long."}

  private

    def cheque_transaction?
      self.transaction.transaction_mechanism == "Cheque"
    end
```

end

Comment: 1. "The banking information validations should only be triggered when the parent's (transaction) transaction_mechanism field is set to "cheque".
 2.For some reason when I set the transaction_mechanism to "cheque" in the form, it's still calling the banking information form validations"

So the transaction_mechanism is set to 'cheque' type so it's getting called? what' the problem then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial and error- I found a way to get my conditional validation to work. I first changed the model name from 'Transaction' to 'AccountTransaction'. I did this to comply with the conventions of rails after I found out 'Transaction' is a reserved word in rails.

Once I changed the model name, I appended my association with inverse_of: :account_transaction. More can be read about inverse_of [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

**account_transaction.rb**

```
class AccountTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Require packages
  require 'time'

  # Associations
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :banking_information_form, inverse_of: :account_transaction

  # Nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :banking_information_form

  # Validations
  validates_associated :banking_information_form
  validate  :check_debit_or_credit
  validates :transaction_mechanism, :transaction_kind, :debit, :salesforce_id, presence: true
  validate  :debit, :credit,numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

**banking_information_form.rb**

```
class BankingInformationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :account_transaction

  # Validations
  validates :financial_institution, :transit_number, :bank_account_number, presence: true, :unless => :cheque_transaction?
  validates :transit_number, length: {is: 5,
                                  too_short: "Your transit number is 5 digits long.",
                                  too_long: "Your transit number is 5 digits long."}, :unless => :cheque_transaction?
  validates :bank_account_number, length: {minimum: 4, maximum: 12,
                                  too_short: "Your bank account number will be between 4 and 12 digits long.",
                                  too_long: "Your bank account number will be between 4 and 12 digits long."}, :unless => :cheque_transaction?

  private

    def cheque_transaction?
      self.account_transaction.transaction_mechanism == "Cheque"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :banking_information_form
  # Other code 
end
```

As you described, your banking informations will be validated only when the parent(transcactions) mechanism is not 'Cheque' :

```
class BankingInformationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transaction #this was missing in your code.

  validates :financial_institution, :transit_number, 
    :bank_account_number, presence: true, unless: :cheque_transaction?
  # other validations here 

  private 
   def cheque_transaction?
     transaction.transaction_mechanism == "Cheque"
   end
end
```

Comment: I previously had the same belongs_to statement in the banking information form model but received a ton of strange errors. After some more research after your answer I think it has something to do with 'Transaction' being a reserved word in rails? I may have to modify the name of the model. I'll post back with my results. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the model name of Transaction and copied your answer and am still getting the same result.